# What is an elegant way to delete until the first line?

Tags: cursor-motions

I know that I can delete until the first character with `dgg` or until line 1 with `d1 Shift-G`.

But I would prefer something conceptually elegant if possible.

I guess I can easily just remap a single key to `d2 Shift-G`, but I’m still not clear on how you find or decide what key to map to, in case you overwrite something important.

Is there any syntax of Vim native built-ins which possibly says:

“Delete until the line one beneath the first”.

For example, maybe there is something I could add between `d` and `gg` which says “+1” wherever you are going?

Or is there a special code like `gg` but for the second line?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the following command:

```
:2,.d
```

The `2,.` is the range on which `d` is applied it goes from the second line to the current line (`.`)

And you can map that to whatever you want:

```
nnoremap <leader>d :2,.d<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s pretty good. But why is it so common to map to commands with the leader key? Why not just map to a key by itself? Thank you

Comment: Well you said `I’m still not clear on how you find or decide what key to map to, in case you overwrite something important.` and I think that's exactly the reason why you should use mappings with the leader key. My personal rule of thumb is never override a built-in feature, only create mapping which don't already exists and `<leader>` help a lot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I delete large amount of lines, I generally prefer to first do a selection and then delete the selection.

So first I start the selection and would go to the top of the file: <kbd>vgg</kbd>

Then I'd move to the first line I want to delete with arrow keys.

Finally, I'd hit either <kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd> to delete what is selected, or all the lines selected.

If I were to need to do that many times, I'd create a macro

> <kbd>qa<type your sequence of commands>q</kbd>

To then apply the macro you do:

> <kbd>@a</kbd>

You can repeat the last macro you used with:

> <kbd>@@</kbd>

As for which keys to remap, I don't use many remapped commands, but I have them on my <kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> keys. Those are not used by vim anyway. For example, to write the signature in a Debian `changelog` file, I use <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```
map <F5> 0C -- Alexis Wilke <alexis@example.com>  <C-R>=strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")<CR><Esc>
```